# Function and equivalence relations question

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

1. Let A and B be subsets of the set Z of all integers, and let F denote the set of all functions
   f : A to B. Define a relation R on F by: for any f,g element of F, fRg if and only if f - g is a
   constant function; that is, there is a constant c so that f(x) - g(x) = c for all x element of A.

   ```
   (a) Prove that R is an equivalence relation on F.
   (b) Suppose that A = B = Z. Let Iz be the identity function on Z so Iz(x) = x 
       for all x element of Z. Find a function f (6)= Iz which belongs to the
       equivalence class [Iz].
   ```

   Assume that A={1,2,3} and B={1,2,...,n} where n >= 2 is a fixed integer

   ```
   (c) Let f1 element of F be defined by: f1(1) = 2, f1(2) = n, f1(3) = 1.
       (As a set ofordered pairs, f1 = {(1,2), (2,n), (3,1)}
       Suppose that g element of F is arbitrary so that gRf1. 
       Prove that g = f1, and thus the equivalence class [f1] is just {f1}.
   ```

Comment: Any help is appreciated

Comment: Checking that a relation is an equivalence relation means checking it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. Which one do you have a problem with?

Comment: Part (a) is just a matter of checking that $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, all of which are very easy to check; have you made any progress there?

Comment: Im having a hard time proving those three requirements for the equivalence relation

Comment: Start easy: Reflexivity means $f R f$ for all $f$. Is $f-f$ always a constant function?

Comment: Yes it is so that one is good. How about the next one?

Comment: Are you taking 271 with Thi ? Is it for Assignment 4, because I might have some answers if so.

Comment: Not with Thi but I assume it is the same assignment

Comment: I added more to the original question that I also need help with

Comment: @Nic Have you been successful with the rest of the assignment?

Answer (score 1):

HINTS: For (a):

- **Reflexivity:** What is $f(n)-f(n)$? Does it depend on $n$?
- **Symmetry:** If $f(n)-g(n)=k$, what is $g(n)-f(n)$?
- **Transitivity:** If $f(n)-g(n)=k$ and $g(n)-h(n)=\ell$, what is $f(n)-h(n)$?

For (b): You want a function $f:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$, different from $I_{\Bbb Z}$, such that $f(n)-I_{\Bbb Z}(n)$ is a constant that does not depend on $n$. Note that $f(n)-I_{\Bbb Z}(n)=f(n)-n$. Can you find a function $f$ such that $f(n)-n$ is always $2$, say? Or $7$? Or any other fixed integer?

Comment: Ok I understant (a) but I am still struggling with part (b).

Comment: @Dan: If $f(n)-n=2$ for all $n$, then $f(n)=\ldots$ what function of $n$?

Comment: would it be n+2? im sorry for being so terrible at this

Comment: @Dan: Yes, it would: the function $f(n)=n+2$ has the property that $f(n)-I_{\Bbb Z}(n)=2$ for every integer $n$, so $fRI_{\Bbb Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if f belongs to the equivalence class [Iz],  f(x)-x=c, c being a constant. So f(x)=x (mod c). Since congruence is an equivalent relation, I would say that any function f, where f(x) - Iz(x) is equal to a multiple of c, that belongs to the equivalent class [Iz]. I'm really not sure about that :)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Please try to give concise, precise and checked answers. Not only this person will see your answer, and will want to rely on it.